# Best way to handle Messages with different properties

Tags: c#, c++-cli, messaging, midi

this question might seem a bit.. insignificant, however ever since I had information technology last semester, I can't stop thinking about the best possible implementation for whatever problem I happen to face..

Now here's the thing, I have a chain of midi message processing functions, however some functions are for modifying a special property of the message only, that only certain messages have.

For example, the processing function is given a Midi message and its supposed to modify the Note property, if the message has one.

Now possible ways of doing this are:

- Implementing an INote interface.
- Implementing a class for each message type and comparing the ones applicable for having a note property
- implementing a "HasNote" Property
- Just modify the Note property of the class, which then throws an exception, if no such property exists.
- properly quite a few other possibilities.

Now I'm wondering which one is the most efficient in terms of performance and amount of code to be written.

There is probably a whole book about this stuff, however I wouldn't know where to start looking^^

Regards,
Xaser

Answer (score 1):

MIDI was designed in the early 1980s, engineered to operate on the kind of machines that were available back then.  It only sends data at 31.25 kbaud, at least 1500x times slower than your network card.  The machines from the 1980s were about 1000x times slower than the one you have on your desktop today.  Midi message rates are about 1000 per second, your machine can execute 5 *million* instructions on a single midi message and not fall behind.

In other words, you are trying to solve a problem you don't have.  Write simple understandable code that you can maintain.  A switch() statement on the midi message status byte will work just fine.  And of course get a book, Amazon has [plenty to choose from](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=midi%20programming&rh=n:283155,k%3amidi%20programming).

Comment: it's not midi I'm lacking information about, I know that its rather slow, however even modern midi software should try not to unnecessarily increase the latency of the midi signals. Its much more about how to keep the code simple. Having a separate class for each message type, makes things easy in the processing function, however requires to implement lots of stuff. Having a "Master-Message-Class" will probably make the code confusing. I probably shouldn't worry that much though...

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but some thoughts on it (as I've come across processing midi recently). The granularity of the original data that you offer your processing functions, may matter more than the representation (the message inheritance structure, properties, whatever). So you can ask yourself: Should I decompose/parse each data package on arrival (in, say, different messages with different types, ...) or should I wrap the raw data in a generic message object and only extract the single fields when neccessary? Well, this depends on what your processing looks like, but - er - as Hans Passant already said, would in the case of midi not have a perfomance impact at all.

However sometimes it makes sense to 'think through' a solution that fullfills the design needs more than it has to. Especially if you later plan building a more abstract solution out of it.

Regarding midi here's another trick (adapted from an example in [C#5 in a Nutshell [Albahari]](http://www.amazon.de/5-0-Nutshell-The-Definitive-Reference/dp/1449320104)) for the data representation. As long as midi messages are segmented in 1byte-sized parts you can build a struct (following code is C#) with a 4byte integer for the full message and overlapping byte fields for the different message attributes. Take this as an example how field access might be optimized:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct NativeMidi 
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint PackedMsg;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte ChannelAndStatus;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte Value1;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte Value2;
}
```

I don't know if this helps in you in getting what you want, but I guess your question was rather theroretical. Finding *the most efficient in terms of performance and amount of code* seems hard anyhow...

Comment: In fact you aren' late at all. I had to put that project on hold for a while and I'm actually still not quite done with the lib yet. I started however to do a mix of your suggestion and an abstract representation for each "major" midi package type (channel, sys etc). But I will try to think all possibilities through :)